# How can I make Clang optimize redundant read of atomic when its value is know ahead of time?

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, atomic, compiler-optimization

Here we have three similar functions. They all **always** return `0`.

This first function is optimized well. The compiler sees that `x` is always `1`.

```cpp
int f1()
{
    std::atomic<int> x = 1;
    if (x.load() == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```yaml
f1():                                 # @f3()
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

This second function is more interesting. The compiler realized that subtracting `0` from `x` doesn't do anything and so the operation was omitted. However, it doesn't notice that `x` is always `1` and does a `cmp`arison. Also, despite using `std::memory_order_relaxed` an `mfence` instruction was emitted.

```cpp
int f2()
{
    std::atomic<int> x = 1;
    if (x.fetch_sub(0, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```yaml
f2():                                 # @f2()
        mov     dword ptr [rsp - 4], 1
        mfence
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsp - 4]
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     ecx, 1
        setne   al
        ret
```

Finally, this is the real example of what I'm trying to optimize. What I'm really doing is implementing a simple `shared_pointer` and `x` represents the reference counter. I'd like the compiler to optimize the case when a temporary `shared_pointer` object is created and destroyed and avoid the needless atomic operation.

```cpp
int f3()
{
    std::atomic<int> x = 1;
    if (x.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```yaml
f3():                                 # @f3()
        mov     dword ptr [rsp - 4], 1
        xor     eax, eax
        lock            dec     dword ptr [rsp - 4]
        setne   al
        ret
```

I am using clang. How can  I make it optimize `f3` like it did with `f1`?

Comment: The use of stack based (local to a function) atomics is probably quite rare.  What is your real use-case?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45960387) which discusses the fact that compilers don't optimize atomics in general.  I was surprised clang managed to optimize away even `f1`, I guess due to escape analysis and lack of any atomic RMWs. Also [Why do relaxed atomic operations prevent compiler optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70578990)

Comment: @RichardCritten This is my real use-case. The `atomic` I am showing here is a member of my `shared_pointer`. However, here I show it inlined. This shared pointer is actually a shared coroutine that I use in my [job system](https://github.com/janekb04/job_system/tree/main).

Comment: So your `shared_pointer` keeps its ref count in the `shared_pointer` object itself, not in a dynamically allocated control block that `shared_pointer` objects reference?

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, I used a simplification. A C++20 coroutine has a "promise" and a "return object" that function as a _Promise_ and _Future_ pair. My `promise_type` stores the atomic reference count of its coroutine as a member. The `promise_type` is suballocated within its coroutine's coroutine frame. The coroutines themselves are typically allocated on the stack, thanks to HALO. So, if I have a coroutine `A` that runs and immediately `co_await`s a coroutine `B`, then: the coroutine frame of `B`, the refcount to `B` and the return object's pointer to `B`'s refcount are all on `A`'s stack.

Comment: Ok, so there's probably no hope of having the object optimize away completely like `f1`, that's probably too much going on with passing a reference to it to something that looks like a function call.  Perhaps what you actually need is a `shared_pointer` that's only safe for use within a single thread, since a coroutine runs as part of the same OS-level thread.  That means your increment/decrement don't need to be atomic on a machine level, since it's basically cooperative multi-tasking; a coroutine switch won't happen in the middle of a `count++`, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, it is true that a coroutine switch will not happen in the middle of `count++`. However, I can copy a coroutine's future and send it to a different thread. Then, two threads have futures referencing the same coroutine. Then, both threads can copy their futures again and that will be two concurrent calls to `count++`.

Comment: Ok yeah, then your use-case does rule out the idea of taking advantage of being a single thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes OOC, Intel optimized also `f2` (but not `f3`): https://godbolt.org/z/Yvq3TcqnY

Comment: @DanielLangr: Interesting.  And that's ICX, LLVM-based, so maybe there's hope for clang.  Their classic ICC (2021.7.1 https://godbolt.org/z/7xPzz3qhn) doesn't optimize any of them at all, and amusingly emits broken Intel-syntax asm (like `lock xaddl ecx, (rdx)` - I guess it only know how to print AT&T syntax properly for its atomic RMWs.)