# Can a compiler invent multiple loads when compiling one std::atomic load using memory_order_relaxed?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, stdatomic

Taking the following piece of code

```cpp
struct SharedMemory
{
  std::atomic<float> value;

  bool shouldReturnTrue()
  {
    float tmp = value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    float a = tmp;
    float b = tmp;
    return a == b;
  }
};
```

Is it legal for the compiler to optimize it as follow and so break the thread safety ?

```cpp
struct SharedMemory
{
  std::atomic<float> value;

  bool shouldReturnTrue()
  {
    float a = value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    float b = value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return a == b;
  }
};
```

If so, should I force it to not optimize `tmp` using `volatile` keyword as follow ?

```cpp
struct SharedMemory
{
  std::atomic<float> value;

  bool shouldReturnTrue()
  {
    volatile float tmp = value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    float a = tmp;
    float b = tmp;
    return a == b;
  }
};
```

Comment: `std::memory_order` is used to 'constraint' **between** atomic operation. here you have only one atomic operation.

Comment: `volatile` is unrelated to threading or atomic operation.

Comment: Do you mean that even without specifying `std::memory_order_relaxed` I should use `volatile` anyway ?

Comment: You should probably never use `volatile` (unless you use special memory).

Comment: You need to read about atomics in something like a textbook. Guessing your way through atomics is pretty much impossible.

Comment: Of course it's illegal. All the weirdness of `memory_order_relaxed` only affects what number `load` can return (in this case). It doesn't allow the compiler to remove `tmp` completely.

Answer (score 1):

**No, that wouldn't be a legal optimization.**  As you say, it could return false for cases other than `tmp` being NaN, if there was a writer.  Therefore it wouldn't be valid per the as-if rule, because the C++ abstract machine does always return `!isnan(tmp)`.

(If you'd picked a type like `int` where `self == self` was always true, it would be easier to talk about!)

The transformation you ask about is *only* legal for non-atomic variables, precisely because the value can be assumed not to be changing.  If it is, that would be data-race undefined behaviour, and compilers are allowed to assume no UB.  Thus they can invent another non-atomic non-volatile load if that's more convenient for register allocation.

But an `atomic` variable does have to be assumed to change value between any two reads (in *this way* similar to `volatile` in terms of what compilers have to assume about it), because that *is* well-defined behaviour that compilers have to respect.

**So the compiler will never [invent reads](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/#Invented%20Loads) of `atomic<>` objects**.  (That linked article is about Linux kernel code, where they use `volatile` for hand-rolled atomics on compilers [that are known to work the way they want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118), for the same reasons we use `std::atomic<>` in modern C++.)

`memory_order_relaxed` means that the *ordering* wrt. surrounding memory accesses is relaxed, not the atomicity guarantees.  In this respect, `relaxed` isn't different from `acquire` or `seq_cst`.  I guess you had some misconception that `relaxed` might be relevant here, but it isn't.

---

You're right that assigning the load result to `volatile float tmp` would make it less likely for a compiler to want to invent loads, but if that was a real problem (it isn't), a better way would be to use `volatile atomic<float> value;`.  Again, this is **not necessary**.  Especially now, since compilers currently don't optimize atomics at all ([Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960387/why-dont-compilers-merge-redundant-stdatomic-writes)) but even in future with compilers that only give you the bare minimum ISO C++ standard and do optimize atomics by e.g. coalescing redundant back-to-back reads into one, they *won't* be allowed to do the other thing and invent extra writes, or invent extra reads and assume the value is the same.