# Is there a situation where a std::atomic<T> should be marked as volatile?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, interrupt, volatile

What would be a scenario where you would want to mark `std::atomic<T>` or `std::atomic_flag` as `volatile` (if there is one)?

What about a `std::atomic_flag` that's used in an interrupt handler? Does that need to be marked as `volatile`?

Comment: I think it would help if you read what the books says and question certain statements instead of just "what about..." it all. Focus.

Comment: @273K `volatile` is not being deprecated. The point of the linked answer is that some specific uses of `volatile` that weren't well-defined or easily misunderstood are deprecated.

Comment: You need `volatile` in the same way it is needed for non-atomic object. If you want e.g. a store to the atomic to observably happen on the real machine, e.g. because it writes to memory-mapped IO, then you need `volatile`. Compilers are allowed to optimize `atomic` stores just like normal stores as long as none of the memory order guarantees are violated and some store eventually becomes visible to other threads. However, in practice compilers are reluctant to perform such optimizations even without `volatile`.

Comment: Related: http://wg21.link/n4455 / http://wg21.link/p0062 / [Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45960387) .  You don't need `volatile` for any of the `atomic<>` guarantees to work, even between a thread and an interrupt/signal handler.  The way compilers currently work, C++ `atomic` [maps to asm](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) in ways that will work with any hypothetical UB-free observer, whether or not such functions exist in this program.

Comment: Another potentially interesting use case is a variable used in the `setjmp`/`longjmp` situation.  (That functionality inherited from C is rather ill-behaved in C++, and probably should (almost?) never be used because it doesn't unwind the stack it just abandons the intervening portion of the stack.)